# OWIN and Katana - What the middlewares really are?

Tags: asp.net, owin, katana

When working with Katana Project we deal a lot with middlewares. On ASP.NET website they say

> As previously mentioned, when the server accepts a request from a
>   client, it is responsible for passing it through a pipeline of OWIN
>   components, which are specified by the developer’s startup code. These
>   pipeline components are known as middleware.

That's fine but I quite don't get it. At first I thought that middlewares were the ASP.NET components like WebAPI, SignalR and all of that. However, when studying authentication I saw the Cookie Authentication Middleware. This one is not an entire framework like WebAPI so it doesn't fit my initial idea of middleware.

So what Katana middlewares really are? They are just pieces of code that can be integrated on the execution pipeline and do work on the environment dictionary? And so, they can be simple components like an authentication middleware or interfaces to communicate with entire frameworks like WebAPI?

Comment: For anyone who's not already aware, the source for Katana is available, so you can see how the various modules work in detail [here](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/). For example, if you look in the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationExtensions` class you can see how extension methods are used to allow you to register middleware modules with your `IAppBuilder`.

Answer (score 6):

Middlewares are as simple as thinking of mathematical function composition. The OWIN [(nearly) spec'd signature](https://github.com/owin/owin/issues/6) is `Func<AppFunc, AppFunc>`, where `using AppFunc = Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>`.

If you think in terms of function composition, the purpose becomes clear:

```
val f : int -> int
let f x = x*x

val g : int -> int
let g x = x+x
```

You can call these manually:

```
val result1 : int -> int
let result1 x = g(f(x))
```

Or you can compose the functions to create a new function:

```
val result1 : int -> int
let newFunc = g • f
// or in F#
let newFunc = g << f
```

Back to OWIN, again using F# notation to keep it simple:

```
type AppFunc = IDictionary<string, obj> -> Task
val app : AppFunc
val middleware : AppFunc -> AppFunc
```

Applying my `app` to `middleware` creates a new `app'`:

```
let app' : AppFunc = middleware app
```

A concrete example is that of a logging middleware. Following the composition, you will find that the request flows like this:

```
request -> loggingMiddleware -> app -> loggingMiddleware -> response
```

giving you an opportunity to log both the incoming request and outgoing response. This is effectively the same as Web API's `HttpMessageHandler`.

Katana makes this simpler for C# developers through `IAppBuilder` and the `.Use` extension, as well as each middleware library exposing a shortcut extension method, such as `.UseWebApi` or `.UseSignalR`.

Also, Katana uses middlewares to mount frameworks so that it can use a fall-through mechanism, based on a 404 response status code, to try to handle the request with another framework. You can handle this differently by just [mounting frameworks at different paths](https://github.com/panesofglass/TodoBackendFSharp/blob/master/TodoBackendFSharp/Startup.fs#L78-83), but this mechanism works well if you want to handle different parts of your app under a unified path using different frameworks.

Comment: Then why isn't it a monad?  It would certainly make [LINQ to OWIN](https://linqtoowin.codeplex.com) a bit simpler. ;)

Comment: @DaveSexton See https://github.com/fsprojects/dyfrig/blob/master/src/Dyfrig/OwinApp.fs#L35-113 :)

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is the ASP.NET team on board for defining the Katana interfaces as a monad?

Comment: @DaveSexton I highly doubt it, though it doesn't hurt that it can be wrapped easily using Lenses. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with ASP.NET application lifecycle and its processing pipeline,

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline

You probably get some basic ideas about what is the middleware. The pipeline itself (mainly types in System.Web) is a middleware, that bridges your ASP.NET applications (WebForms, MVC) to the underlying host (web servers, such as IIS, IIS Express, Cassini, selfhost and so on).

However, the classic System.Web is highly coupled, and then comes OWIN and Katana. If you do dive into Katana's code base, you will see itself is a pipeline. It is much more flexible and highly customizable, so saying it as middleware is now more concise than ever.

ASP.NET vNext completely gets rid of System.Web, so that you can see how Katana plays an important role in the next few months.

Comment: What is the difference between Katana and vNext?

Comment: @MichałDudak still a little bit confused. both are basically doing the same thing(proting OWIN). this is totally overload for .net developers, i mean, we now have two different tech stack to learn, right?

Comment: Katana has been there for a few months already, and aimed to be the Microsoft implementation of OWIN. But note that ASP.NET vNext is more ambitious a plan than ever, so no one could tell if Katana can fulfill the needs. Based on the current code observation, we can only say that ASP.NET vNext does not directly use Katana for some reasons, but we could not tell the future. It is possible that finally some changes go to Katana, or they are just in vNext. I try not to draw any conclusion at this moment.